# Import multiple CSV files excluding duplicate values SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

I'm trying to load multiple CSV files into an access db but only want to import unique values from the first column (PID). I have the below routine which will work the first time but it crashes out if i try and import a file with a duplicate value (all files will have only one occurrence of each PID)

My CSVs are slightly irregular as well as the headers start from the 2nd line down, but for testing I've actually deleted the 1st line but would need to accommodate this as well

Any suggestions?

```
Dim OpenMe As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim FileStr As String = Nothing

OpenMe.Title = "Please Locate Your Outlets File"
OpenMe.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
OpenMe.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv) | *.csv"
OpenMe.Multiselect = False
OpenMe.ShowDialog()
FileStr = OpenMe.FileName

TextBox1.Text = FileStr

Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Dropbox\ROutlets\OutletsDB.accdb;")
conn.Open()
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Outlets] ([PID], [Category], [Sub Category], [Tertiary Category], [Description], [Pack Description] ) SELECT DISTINCT [PID], [Category], [Sub Category], [Tertiary Category], [Description], [Pack Description] FROM [Text;Database=C:\Users\Tset\Desktop;Hdr=Yes].[outlet-products111.csv] ", conn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
MsgBox("File Imported")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DISTINCT` is not working for you because values in other columns are different on the subsequent rows.

I would do this in two stages.

1. Insert the rows into a temporary table that does not have a primary key constraint on it
2. Use other logic (SQL or VB) to work out which records you insert into `[Outlets]`

Alternatively, you will have to iterate through each record and then test whether you should be doing an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE` for each one.